# If $X$ is distributed exponentially with $\lambda=2$, how can I find $Y=\sqrt{X}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a random variable $X$, that is distributed exponentially with $\lambda=2$.
Therefore it's probability density function is as follows:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, &  x \leq0\\ 2\cdot e^{-2x}, &  x >0 \end{cases}$$
and it's probability distribution function would be:
 $$F(x) = \begin{cases} 0, &  x \leq0\\ 1- e^{-2x}, &  x >0,\lambda>0 \end{cases}$$

How can I get probability density function of $Y=\sqrt{X}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(Y > t) = P(\sqrt{X} > t) = P(X >t^2) = e^{-2t^2}$

So $P(Y\leq t) = 1 - e^{-2t^2}, t\geq 0$. Take derivative with respect to $t$ to get the density function